# How to re-apply to a company after rejecting a job interview?

Tags: interviewing, work-environment, job-search, job-offer

I've rejected a job interview offer where I think that the position they offer is not suitable for me. In the future, if I want to move to their company, how long should I wait before re-applying?

What if they ask about why rejected the earlier interview?
And is it possible that I could get shortlisted?

Answer (score 4):

Most companies when hiring wouldn't put arbitrary time limits on applications like that. They want to get the best person for the role, they're not out to repay a past rejection.

What you do need, though, is a convincing answer to

> What if they ask about why rejected the earlier interview?

Basically: 'the other role was not suitable for me because ..., but this one is very suitable because ...' That may include life factors outside your career, which may even apply if it's the same role - temporary family commitments, personal development in the intervening time, and so on. *However* they may well have a record of the way you rejected them, so what you say now must be absolutely consistent with that. You're not going to have an easy time if, say, you blew them off first time about how bad their salary offer was if it hasn't changed in the meantime.

Answer (score -3):

First, the note on semantics/vocabulary:

You DON'T reject a job offer, you decline it. If you don't know the difference,it's your problem.

Second, the tutorial on the reason for cooling periods:

A cooling interval is appropriate if you applied for a position and got rejected for that position - There is no point to being rejected again by the same people for the same reason. However, don't conflate that circumstance with you declining a proposition for an interview.

Third,regarding your specific question:

There is no reason why you shouldn't be able to change your mind about interviewing with a prospective employer within 24 hours of either your circumstances changing or your perception of your circumstances changing. You simply write them,using their contact info, notify them that your circumstances have changed, and ask them to schedule an interview. That's assuming that you declined the original invitation for your interview and that you didn't reject it,of course - Being perceived as rude does not usually open doors for you.

Comment: From the question, it seems it was an interview that was declined, not an offer.

Comment: @LaconicDroid I got that when I wrote my answer. I made three points: 1. You don't reject a job offer, you decline it; 2. Waiting/cooling periods are for the situation where you applied and got rejected; 3. You can change your mind about deciding whether to apply with an employer any time your circumstances change. I have no idea why I am coming across as unclear.

Comment: It's unclear because the question is asking about the specific situation of declining an interview. It's a different situation from declining a job offer or having an application rejected.